# Restoring mysqldump into mariadb still not complete after 28 hrs

Tags: mariadb

**[RESOLVED]**

I've been trying to restore a MariaDB backup into a new database instance and the dump is about 2.5GB in size (uncompressed, 250MB gzipped). The database dump was created using the below command and came from our Staging environment.

```
mysqldump \
      --defaults-extra-file="${MYSQLDUMP_CONFIG}" \
      --host="${DB_HOST}" \
      --port="${DB_PORT}" \
      --opt \
      --skip-extended-insert \
      --single-transaction \
      --routines \
      "$db" | gzip -c >"${backup_output_file}"
```

(The MYSQLDUMP_CONFIG contains only the username and password needed to connect with).

When trying to restore the database created this way, into either mariadb 10.6.7 or 10.5.5   it just doesn't complete in a reasonable time. For curiosity I've tried letting it run to see if it would complete, and after 28+hrs it still hadn't.

The in question dump contains the schema for `voipmonitor` which is about 174 tables, some stored procedures, and the rest is data.  (The schema alone is about 534k of that, and the rest is ~9 million rows of data).

For local testing I'm running MariadDB in a docker image using the following docker-compose config (in prod/staging it's being written to a MariaDB galera cluster).

```
---
version: '3.6'
services:
  sql:
    image: mariadb:10.6.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: compose
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./schemas/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - "./mariadb-config:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
```

And the custom config being passed to it is as below (the same behaviour occurs without the below configuration and just the default image configuration):

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8mb4

key_buffer_size=32M
myisam_recover_options=FORCE,BACKUP
skip_host_cache
skip_name_resolve
max_allowed_packet=128M
max_connect_errors=1000000
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
sysdate_is_now=1
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
log_bin=mysql-bin
tmp_table_size=32M
max_heap_table_size=32M
# Re-enabling as now works with Maria 10.1.2
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_size=256M
max_connections=500
thread_cache_size=50
open_files_limit=65535
table_definition_cache=4096
table_open_cache=4096

innodb=FORCE
innodb_strict_mode=1
# Mandatory per https://github.com/codership/documentation/issues/25
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
# Per https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/04/innodb-double-write/
innodb_doublewrite=1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_log_file_size=128M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_file_per_table=1
# 80% Memory is default reco.
# Need to re-evaluate when DB size grows
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
```

The corresponding problem with the above backup is also that if I extract only the schema from the dump (just dropping all the insert statements from the file) I cannot load the schema.  The below error doesn't show up in the import after 28 hours because it still hasn't gotten past the tables containing the majority of the data that are earlier up in the dump file.

The database is created via:

```
 CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `voipmonitor`
      DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Loading the schema nets me the following error (either via piping the schema to the mysql client or using `SOURCE schemafile.sql` in the client):

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `voipmonitor`.`sensors` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

The corresponding CREATE TABLE in question does not have any foreign key constraints. If I loaded the schema using `SOURCE` I can cut the table down to a single column of any of the below data types and it will fail with the foreign key constraint.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sensors`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `sensors` (
  `id_sensor` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `port` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remote_mysql_host` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remote_mysql_db` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remote_mysql_user` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remote_mysql_pass` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interface` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tcpdump_folder` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tcpdump_mount_folder` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone_offset` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone_save_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `cloud_router` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_for_active_call` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 1,
  `read_timeout` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `color_background` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color_chart` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_server` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `all_clients_in_active_calls` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `override_international_rules` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `international_prefixes` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `international_number_min_length` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `international_number_min_length_prefixes_strict` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code_for_local_numbers` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enable_check_napa_without_prefix` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_length_napa_without_prefix` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `skip_prefixes` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `override_country_prefixes` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_upgrade` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_upgrade_at` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_upgrade_week_days` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_upgrade_email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_upgrade_enable_beta` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_upgrade_last_run_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `disable` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_spool` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_sensor`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Fun fact, if I create the database using the above, and ONLY create the above table, it works fine.  But with the full schema of the database, it barfs with the above.

After trying to load the schema using SOURCE, getting the error/warning, you can run this and still get the same error

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `sensors` (`id_sensor` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `voipmonitor`.`sensors` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Meaning that something in the schema file or MariaDB is causing things to fail (there are 149 create table instructions of the exact same form prior to this `sensors` table).

I've tried many different things to resolve both of these issues, but being unable to even load the database schema without things breaking is making it really difficult to fiddle with the performance of the database load commands.

Any suggestions or recommendations on fixing would be great.

Edit #1: I've increased the memory available to the local docker image test restore to 8G and increased the `max_allowed_packet` to 512M, and the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 6G.

Sofar this seems to be behaving a little better when piping the SQL dump into mysql.  And after  2.5 hours it does on the foreign key issue.

Edit #2: There are 2 foreign key references to the `sensors` table I expected to be loaded afterwards but are in fact loaded prior and left "pending" application during the restore.  These foreign key references were created on column definitions with `int(11)` whilst the table column they were referencing is of type `int(10) unsigned`.
I've removed the broken foreign key references and will deal with them later.

Edit #3: Schema contained some really fun to pinpoint foreign key references to columns that no longer exist in the tables being referred to.

Prior version of the schema had (excerpt, material not needed omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE `billing_customer_assignment_sensors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_customer_assignment` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_sensor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk__billing_customer_assignment_sensors` (`id_customer_assignment`),
  KEY `fk__billing_customer_assignment_sensors2` (`id_sensor`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__billing_customer_assignment_sensors` FOREIGN KEY (`id_customer_assignment`) REFERENCES `billing_customer_assignment` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk__billing_customer_assignment_sensors2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_sensor`) REFERENCES `sensors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `sensors` (
  `id_sensor` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
```

So what we can see here is that there was an original Foreign Key reference to the `id` column, but that column has since been removed from the table yet the foreign key for it still exists (I would have expected a serious error being raised if someone tried to do this).

Edit #4: Problem resolved after all of the above edits and some performance improvements by tweaking MariaDB resulted in the local docker image import to finish in <3 hrs, which then allowed for a more performance friendly export to be made to apply to the actual database server in the environment.

Edit #5: Progress update, entire DB now restored in 22 minutes.

Comment: On speed, recommend increasing  [innodb_log_file_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_file_size) and [innodb_io_capacity](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_io_capacity) to your provisioned IOPs. On the phantom Foreign key constraint, please create a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) and include a `--no-data` version of your dump, indirectly via [ftp](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/meta/mariadb-ftp-server/) if that suites you better. Extended insert disabled with `--skip-extended-insert` will increase load speed on later MariaDB versions.

Comment: Is there another table that references `sensors` in its FK constraints? What is its definition?

Comment: Yes, there are other tables that reference it at a later stage in the import but it doesn't get to those, the error occurs prior to it.  The phantom Foreign key constraint issue seems to be related to the character and collation set being used and something happening to that in the earlier part of the restore.  At this stage I cannot provide a no-data version of the dump, the reason I'm restoring is due to a DB crash with the end result of the DB getting replaced instead of repaired (time constraints).